# Jasmine context + Typescript

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine with Typescript and recently we started using the `this` context in `beforeEach` and `it`.

Example:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(blablabla);
});

it('should do something', () => {
   expect(this.fixture).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The problem is that TypeScript is not smart enough to figure out that `this` inside `beforeEach` is exactly the same `this` as in `it`. 
Does anyone know an easy way to 'hint' typescript about this fact?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can [typehint `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) in functions. Actually, if you only use arrow functions (in `describe`, `beforeEach` and `it`), the context `this` will be the outermost global context, I suppose. Since that one cannot be annotated, I suggest passing a regular old-style function to the outermost `describe`:

```
// Dummy-type Jasmine functions (only for this MWE)
declare const describe: (msg: string, fun: () => void) => void;
declare const it: (msg: string, fun: () => void) => void;
declare const beforeEach: (fun: () => void) => void;

class A {
    aProperty: string;
}

interface TestSuiteContext {
  myObj: A;
}

describe('Test suite', function (this: TestSuiteContext) {
    beforeEach(() => {
        this.myObj = new A();
    });

    it('should do something', () => {
        const message: string = this.myObj.aProperty;
    });
});
```

Comment: Any chance for simpler solution that would be based more on type inference rather than having to create an interface for each and every test?

Comment: @kubal5003 You can also define it inline: `describe('Test suite', function (this: { myObj: A }) {`. Off the top of my head currently, I can't think of any type inference solution. TypeScript can't know that `beforeEach` will be executed before any `it` code, therefore there must be a definition at least outside `beforeEach`.