# Jasmine/Typescript - using 'this' variable

Tags: typescript, jasmine

In all of our Jasmine unit tests, we use the `this` variable to pass variables and methods around within a `describe` block using `beforeEach` and `it`:

```
import { UnderTest } from './somewhere';

describe('#someMethod', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    this.param = [];
    this.run = () => UnderTest.someMethod(this.param);
  });

  describe('when nothing is provided', () => {
    it('returns an empty object', () => {
      expect(this.run()).toEqual({});
    });
  });
});
```

This has worked great in the past, but once we upgrade our Typescript dependency to 4.x.x, running the tests produce a compiler error of `Object is possibly 'undefined'` for all `this` references.

We are part of an Angular 10 project, and I tried adding `"strictNullChecks": false` to our `tsconfig.spec.json` file but that didn't seem to do anything.  Is using `this` in unit tests a bad idea now?  Is there any way to stay up-to-date with Typescript and suppress these errors?

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be? In the code you have shown, it will always be `undefined`

Comment: @AluanHaddad The function will be bound to a `this` by the Jasmine framework.

Comment: But it's an arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Found a duplicate question with an acceptable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691454/jasmine-context-typescript